# 401 Error Trying to use JWTBearerAuthentication on ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net, azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have been using a variety of tutorials to set up the following scenario:

I have a Mobile Application built on Ionic Framework as a frontend.  I have an ASP.Net Core 1.1.2 Web API as a backend.  I want to authenticate users in the Mobile Application against Azure Active Directory before allowing them to access the API.

Here is my conceptual understanding of how to accomplish this:

1. Register both applications in AAD Portal, one as application type Web App/API (call it WebAPI), and the other as application type Native (call it MobileApp).
2. Add Permission for the MobileApp to access the WebAPI in Delegated Permissions in AAD.
3. Use MobileApp to request a token from AAD.
4. Send token along with any requests to WebAPI.
5. Use app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication middleware to validate tokens and manage access to content from WebAPI.

My first question here is, do I have this strategy correct?  If so, I must be doing something wrong in my implementation of the middleware.

I am currently authenticating against AAD within the app and receiving a token back, with a payload like:

```
{
 "aud": "https://crm.mycompany.com/",
 "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/someID/",
 "iat": 1506539211,
 "nbf": 1506539211,
 "exp": 1506543111,
 "acr": "1",
 "aio": "someOtherID",
 "amr": [
 "pwd"
 ],
 "appid": "appID",
 "appidacr": "0",
 "e_exp": 262800,
 "family_name": "Walter",
 "given_name": "Philip",
 "ipaddr": "someAddress",
 "name": "Philip Walter",
 "oid": "someOtherID",
 "onprem_sid": "someOtherID",
 "puid": "stuff",
 "scp": "user_impersonation",
 "sub": "e_X7WlAoVS2vzXm1pr3kcDOrET7czcC0f8-YRU_2DJ8",
 "tenant_region_scope": "NA",
 "tid": "ourTenantID",
 "unique_name": "pwalter@advtis.com",
 "upn": "pwalter@advtis.com",
 "uti": "RLvLlibQHESwmujVBBdlAA",
 "ver": "1.0"
 }
```

I can send the token along to my API in an `Authentication: Bearer [token]` header, but I receive a `401 Unauthorized` response.  I have been trying to use the following tutorial for my middleware implementation:

[ASP.NET Core Token Authentication Guide](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core)

It seems very straight forward, but obviously I'm missing something.  Here is my Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContext<AdvancedDBContext>();
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseCors(builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
        });

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "https://sts.windows.net/e618ef87-13b6-491b-babf-4e4f4139e3f3/",

                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "https://crm.mycompany.com"

            },
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true
        });
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
}
```

I then use the [Authorize] attribute to protect routes as needed.

The main difference I can tell between this implementation and the one in the tutorial is that I'm not specifying a secret key anywhere, but I'm unsure how to implement that since AAD is issuing the tokens.  Perhaps I need to get one from AAD?

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We also realized something like that recently. From what I understand, you need to specify a Application Client ID and a secret - those need to be passed in the authorization request. Here you find a short tutorial on how to do that in the Azure Portal as well as PowerShell: https://www.netiq.com/communities/cool-solutions/creating-application-client-id-client-secret-microsoft-azure-new-portal/

Comment: Thank you.  I looked through the tutorial this morning, and I generated a key in the Native client application, but I am still unsure how I would use it in my situation.  The procedure in PowerShell doesn't seem to apply.  Any advice on utilizing jwt bearer authentication middleware to validate the token in ASP.Net Core Web API?